# 100mm to twips in LibreOffice

Tags: c++, libreoffice

I have been reading some of the LibreOffice code, and there is [code that converts from 100mm to twips](https://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/core/include/tools/helpers.hxx#59).

Its basic formula is:

```
twips = (n>=0) ? (n*72+63) / 127 : (n*72-63) / 127;
```

Now I know that one twip is 1/20th of a point, and that one inch is 72 points, and 1 inch is 2.54cm, but I cannot work out how the above formula relates to these ratios!

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: It's an assignment expression whose right hand side value is determined via the [ternary conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting together what OP provided:

`n` is the size in 100 mm.

1 inch is 2.54 cm is 25.4 mm.

`inchs = n * 100 / 25.4`
or `inchs = n / (100 * 25.4)`
or `inchs = n / 2540`

1 inch is 72 points.

`points = inchs * 72`

1 `twip` is 1/20th point.

`twips = points / 20`

Now, everything together:

`twips = n / 2540 * 72 / 20`
or `twips = n * 72 / 2540 / 20`
or `twips = n * 72 / 127`

If this is done in `int` arithmetic there will be truncation instead of mathematical rounding. This can be fixed by adding the half of 127 (`127 / 2 = 63`) to `n * 72`:

`twips = (n * 72 + 63) / 127`

This does not handle negative numbers correctly. For these, the 63 has to be subtracted instead:

`twips = n >= 0 ? (n * 72 + 63) / 127) : (n * 72 - 63) / 127;`

and here we are.

As already pointed out by [Ron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8751754/ron), the `?:` operator is the [ternary if-then-else operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

An easier to read (but may be less optimized) replacement would be:

```
if (n >= 0) twips = (n * 72 + 63) / 127);
else twips = (n * 72 - 63) / 127;
```

Comment: Ah, it's the 2540 / 20 that I didn't see. Excellent breakdown!